# Remove prefix from all cell values of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, which looks like the following:

```
 col1                       col2                       col3                ...
 field1:index1:value1     field2:index2:value2       field3:index3:value3  ...
 field1:index4:value4     field2:index5:value5       field3:index5:value6  ...
```

The field is of int type, index is of int type and value could be int or float type.

I want to convert this data frame into the following expected output:

```
 col1              col2                       col3    ...
 index1:value1     index2:value2       index3:value3  ...
 index4:value4     index5:value5       index5:value6  ...
```

I want to remove the all `field:` values from all the cells. How to do this?

EDIT: An example of a cell looks like: `1:1:1.0445731675303e-06` and I would like to reduce such strings to `1:1.0445731675303e-06`, in all the cells.

Comment: is field text ? yes, replace `^field\d*:` with noting

Comment: It is of `int` type. Could be like `1:` and it is different for each column.

Comment: regex only use text. if convert then replace `^\d+:` wit noth

Comment: See my attempt, basically split by phrase after first colon and extract using .str[]

Comment: should i post my comiment as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df
                   col1                  col2                  col3
0       1:index1:value1       2:index2:value2       3:index3:value3
1       1:index4:value4       2:index5:value5       3:index5:value6
```

you can use

```
>>> df.apply(lambda s: s.str.replace('^\d+:', '', regex=True))
            col1           col2           col3
0  index1:value1  index2:value2  index3:value3
1  index4:value4  index5:value5  index5:value6
```

The regex `'^\d+:'` matches the beginnings of strings that start with a sequence of numbers followed by a colon.

Comment: ah ok, my field itself is the number.

Comment: @SumitSidana hm?

Comment: so, basically, each cell looks like `1:1:1.0445731675303e-06`, where `1` is a field in this example. My question was perhaps not fully clear. But, your solution still works if I remove `field` and just keep `\d+` from your solution. Thanks for the solution with `apply`, with `swifter`, it is really fast.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: ':'.join(str(x).split(':')[1:]))
print(df)

            col1           col2           col3
0  index1:value1  index2:value2  index3:value3
1  index4:value4  index5:value5  index5:value6
```

Comment: It works, but, unfortunately, I can accept only 1 answer (Upvoted).

Answer (score 0):

Possible other way is to basically split by phrase after first colon and extract using `.str[index]`

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.str.split('(^[a-z0-9]+\:(.*))').str[-2])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to run the string processing in a list comprehension, and create a new dataframe, using the old dataframe's column names :

```
result = [[":".join(word.split(":")[1:])
          for word in ent]
          for ent in df.to_numpy()]

pd.DataFrame(result, columns = df.columns)

        col1             col2           col3
0   index1:value1   index2:value2   index3:value3
1   index4:value4   index5:value5   index5:value6
```

This is faster than running an `applymap` or `apply`... string processing is usually much faster within python than Pandas.